# Is there a way to use a font from my website inside an iframe

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, font-face

I have a website where I accept payments, it is built with `react`

I am using a credit card processor who provides an iframe to embed in my website to capture the credit card securely the code looks like this.

```
<iframe data-field-id="card-number" src='URL_TO_PROCESSOR_DOMAIN...'/><.iframe>
```

Which displays an input for the credit card number on the page, they also provide a way to pass custom styling to the input like this.

```
let style = {
    "border-color": "red",
    "font-size": "20px"
    ...
}
```

Then you call a function they provide

```
setFieldStype("card-number", style)
```

to apply the style to the generated input.

However I am looking to also pass the `font-family` which I use to the input but it doesn't apply it, I tried it like this.

```
let style = {
    "border-color": "red",
    "font-size": "20px"
    "font-family": "my custom font"
}
```

But it doesn't work since the iframe doesn't have access to my custom imported font.

Is there a way I can accomplish to use a font imported by my website in an iframe?

Comment: Unless you control the page loaded inside the iframe, you can't interfere with the iframe content, which is why an iframe is used in these cases (payment forms, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is only work with the appropriate CORS header is set. We can append a `<link/>` element to your iframe and pass the font file for it.

```
const applyStyle =  () => {
        const linkTag = ele.createElement("link");
        linkTag.id = "custom-link";
        linkTag.href = " link to font... /fonts/custom-font.css";
        linkTag.rel = "stylesheet";
        ele.head.appendChild(linkTag);
 }
```